# How to create a working JDBC connection in Google Cloud Composer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

To get the JDBC Hook working, I first add in the jaydebeapi package in the PYPI packages page in Composer.

However, that alone does not allow a JDBC connection to work:

1) How do I specify the .jar driver path for the JDBC driver I have? 
I was thinking it would be something like "/home/airflow/gcs/drivers/xxx.jar" (assuming I've created a drivers folder in the gcs directory)... but I haven't been able to verify or find documentation on this.

2)How do I install/point toward the Java JRE? On Ubuntu I run this command to install JRE: sudo apt-get install default-jre libc6-i386. Is a JRE or ability to install a JRE available in Cloud Composer?  This is the current error message I get in the Adhoc window with the JDBC connection: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/jvm'

If either of the above options are not currently available, are there any workarounds to get a JDBC connection working with Composer?

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues with JDBC issues in Airflow 1.9 (https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3257); hopefully, we should be able to backport these fixes in Composer by GA!

Comment: Hi Crystal, is there any update of backporting the JDBC fix in?